# Getting Cron Expression from Later.js

Tags: javascript, cron, schedule, laterjs

We are storing schedules as cron expressions in database. The schedules are modified in a web page and I'm using Later.js for this. Works great to parse the Cron expression. Now I would like to output the modified schedule to a Cron expression that can be stored in database.

Is there any "toCronExpression" function in Later.js?

I know I can read the properties of the schedule object and output them myself but I was hoping for a built in function.

Comment: whats this expression intended to look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no such functionality to generate `cron` expressions in `Later.js`. All cron-related functionality has to do with parsing `cron` expressions, not generating them. You can confirm this by looking at all usages of the word `cron` in the master branch of the `Later.js` repository on GitHub. Here is a link to the search:

https://github.com/bunkat/later/search?p=1&q=cron&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93